# Is there a possibility in Java mxGraph to limit cells movement but not disable it?

Tags: java, mxgraph

I am using Java mxGraph and i have deeper nested vertices (on purpose) on 3 levels and now i am trying to keep the innermost vertices(level 3) within their parents(level 2) *without* executing `graph.setCellsMovable(false);`. I have tried to use the parents "bounding box": `graph.setMaximumGraphBounds(graph.getBoundingBox(parent));` but that didn't do what i hoped it would(it didn't do anything visible to me, neither limit the level-3-vertex's movement nor limiting its max size).

So now my question: is there any method that limits the vertex's movement and not disable it? or is  `graph.setCellsMovable(false);` the only option?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is of any help, because I use the javascript version of the library... But I have complex drag and drop rules, so I overridden the mxDragSource.prototype.drop and mxGraphHandler.prototype.mouseUp functions... From there I am able to detect the drop target and implement my own custom rules to allow drag and drop for specific cells. Consider that I have different types of cells, some of them are fixed, some of them can move but only between specific swimlanes or within the same swimlane...

Comment: As i tried over and over again, the only viable mxIEventListener i can create is with mxEvents.Change. I can't use mxEvents.CELLS_MOVED or -.MOVE_CELLS or whatever else there is. it won't even enter the added listener if it is not the .Change Constant.

Comment: I see but I wasn't speaking about implementing other listeners to other events. I simply overridden the above mentionned functions to verify every time the mouse is released if the item can be dropped or not. There I implemented my own custom rules... Maybe in Javascript this is easier, but I believe also in Java it should be possible...

Comment: @Marco Please can u provide an example code as I want to implement this too

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that my use case is the same as yours, but I had issues with cells switching parents on move. So I've overridden the moveCells method in my extension of mxGraph:

```java
    @Override
    public Object[] moveCells(Object[] cells, double dx, double dy, boolean clone, Object target, Point location) {
        // We will not allow cells to change parent, so we move them individually while preserving their parent (by changing the target)
        Object[] movedCells =
                Arrays.stream(cells)
                        .map(cell -> super.moveCells(new Object[] { cell }, dx, dy, clone, ((mxCell) cell).getParent(), location))
                        .flatMap(Arrays::stream).toArray();
        return movedCells;
    }
```

This allows some movement, while preserving the cells' parents. I had issues moving across the boundary of the parent (your level2 vertices I presume). Therefore, the exact geometry of the parent matters.